# Need assistance regarding understanding typedefs and blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
typedef void (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSArray * products);
```

I am having difficulty understanding what this line of code is doing in .h file.

Please explain in detail

1. typedef.
2. void (I know what void do, but whats the purpose here?).
3. (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSArray * products);
4. How to call it?

Comment: Your question is not about typedefs. It is about blocks. Read about blocks. Once that is understood, the typedef is self explaining.

Comment: By the way, the code in question came from the excellent [web page](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/) and [book](http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-6-by-tutorials) tutorials on *In-App Purchase* by the RayWenderlich.com company.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is definition of objective-c [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) type with name `RequestProductsCompletionHandler` that takes 2 parameters (BOOL and NSArray) and does not have return value. You can call it the same way you would call c function, e.g.:

```
RequestProductsCompletionHandler handler = ^(BOOL success, NSArray * products){
    if (success){
       // Process results
    }
    else{
       // Handle error
    }
}
...
handler(YES, array);
```

Answer (score 7):

Vladimir described it well. It defines a variable type which will represent a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW1) that will pass two parameters, a boolean `success` and an array of `products`, but the block itself returns `void`. While you don't need to use the `typedef`, it makes the method declaration a tad more elegant (and avoids your having to engage in the complicated syntax of block variables).

To give you a practical example, one might infer from the name of the block type and its parameters that this defines a completion block (e.g. a block of code to be performed when some asynchronous operation, like a slow network request, completes). See [Using a Block as a Method Argument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW3).

For example, imagine that you had some `InventoryManager` class from which you could request product information, with a method with an interface defined like so, using your `typedef`:

```
- (void)requestProductsWithName:(NSString *)name completion:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completion;
```

And you might use the method like so:

```
[inventoryManager requestProductsWithName:name completion:^(BOOL success, NSArray * products) {

    // when the request completes asynchronously (likely taking a bit of time), this is
    // how we want to handle the response when it eventually comes in.

    for (Product *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"name = %@; qty = %@", product.name, product.quantity);
    }
}];

// but this method carries on here while requestProductsWithName runs asynchronously
```

And, if you looked at the implementation of `requestProductsWithName`, it could conceivably look something like:

```
- (void)requestProductsWithName:(NSString *)name completion:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completion
{
    // initiate some asynchronous request, e.g.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // now do some time consuming network request to get the products here

        // when all done, we'll dispatch this back to the caller

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if (products)
                completion(YES, products); // success = YES, and return the array of products
            else
                completion(NO, nil);       // success = NO, but no products to pass back
        });
    });
}
```

Clearly, this is unlikely to be precisely what your particular completion handler block is doing, but hopefully it illustrates the concept.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Walker created a nice one page site that shows all possibilities to declare a block in Objective-C. This can be helpful to understand your problem as well:

http://fuckingblocksyntax.com

To quote his site, this is how you can define blocks:

**As a local variable:**

```
returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes) = ^returnType(parameters) {...};
```

**As a property:**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes);
```

**As a method parameter:**

```
- (void)someMethodThatTakesABlock:(returnType (^)(parameterTypes))blockName {...}
```

**As an argument to a method call:**

```
[someObject someMethodThatTakesABlock: ^returnType (parameters) {...}];
```

**As a typedef:**

```
typedef returnType (^TypeName)(parameterTypes);
TypeName blockName = ^(parameters) {...}
```